# Accessing postgresql database country-wide

Tags: python, c#, wpf, postgresql

How can I access my postgres database remotely?

I found some info about activating remote access, but it is hard to understand and mostly for linux (i'm using windows 10/postgresql version 13.2).

How can I host this database country wide and access it in Python/C# wpf application?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you're trying to host the DB on your local machine. The main problem here is that you need an address to access your computer over the internet. Generally, providers don't give a static IP address to clients so basically, you got two options:

- Ask your provider for a static IP address (usually you need to pay for it)
- Use something like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to create a tunnel (but if you need a stable tunnel that will run over time, it's also a paid service)

But, if you need a reliable DB storage for more or less production projects, I'd highly recommend to host it somewhere like AWS's RDS. They provide a free-tier instances and you can host your DB there for free during the first year.

Comment: The database i'm trying to host consists of two table with 4 and 6 rows (int, boolean[], json[], char, char[]) and is only for my wpf app with a maximum of 7 clients. I will try to host it. Thanks.